# Extendend LinearLayout - setOnClickListener don't works

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-custom-view

I'm having some trouble when I extend a LinearLayout. 
The onClick event is never fired.

My code:

```
public class Tab extends LinearLayout {

    public Tab(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public Tab(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // ... get attrs ...
        init(context);
    }

    public Tab(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    public void init(Context context) {
        inflate(context, R.layout.tab, this);
        // ... some layout tasks ...
        iconView.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Layout tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_tab"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:duplicateParentState="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@drawable/tab_text_color"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If I put a eventListener on a Tab's child view, it works, but when attached to the Tab itself is doesn't.

Can someone see where my mistake is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just set android:clickable to false on rootView and works! =)